# How to replace values in an existing kendo mediaplayer

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using kendoMediaPlayer, the initial output is okay the video is playing well but I need to update it and upload another video

I tried to destroy first but it didnt work:

```
$("#mediaplayer").data("kendoMediaPlayer").destroy();
$("#mediaplayer").kendoMediaPlayer({
                autoPlay: true,
                navigatable: true,
                media: {
                    title: title,
                    source: (path)
                }
            });
```

I am getting this error:

```
kendo.all.js:204318 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
'removeClass' of undefined
    at init._playStateToggle (kendo.all.js:204318)
    at init.stop (kendo.all.js:204318)
    at init._setPlayerUrl (kendo.all.js:204318)
    at init.media (kendo.all.js:204318)
    at new init (kendo.all.js:204318)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (kendo.all.js:204318)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.e.fn.<computed> [as kendoMediaPlayer] 
(kendo.all.js:204318)
    at PlayVideo (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:1), <anonymous>:71:31)
```

Comment: Why don't you try to set a new media instead of creating a new player? See https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/mediaplayer/methods/media

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$("#mediaplayer").data("kendoMediaPlayer")){
$("#mediaplayer").kendoMediaPlayer({
                autoPlay: true,
                navigatable: true,
                media: {
                    title: title,
                    source: (path)
                }
            });

}
else{
var player = $("#mediaplayer").data("kendoMediaPlayer");
                player.media({
                    title: title,
                    source: (path)
                });
                player.play();
}
```